# Running molecular docking simulation between two proteins

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, software-recommendations, docking

i did run docking simulation between two proteins on HADDOCK server
but now i want to run a simulation of complex (protein+ligand and protein) is it possible with HADDOCK and how can i use it
best regards

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum!

Comment: @ImaneYamari  You cannot run an MD simulation using HADDOCK. You can take the output from the HADDOCK and use MD engines such as GROMACS, NAMD, LAMMPS, etc., to perform the simulations.

Comment: thank you for your suggesting but i'm asking about running molecular docking simulation with Haddock (complex is : Protein with cofactor with another protein)

Comment: @ImaneYamari can you clarify what you mean by molecular docking simulation?